# How can I run a single query with different values at once?

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I have below query where I need to update the date and time every time. Can any one help me in finding out the way by which I can run a single query and can extract result for multiple inputs?

```
select channel
       ,TO_CHAR(ECH.CH_VALIDFROM,'dd/mm/yyyy')
       , count(1) count 
from emcdu.ext_contract_history ech 
where ch_status='a' 
and CH_VALIDFROM BETWEEN TO_DATE('17/10/2018 20:21:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
                 AND TO_DATE ('17/10/2018 21:16:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
and ch_validfrom=(select min(CH_VALIDFROM) 
                  from emcdu.ext_contract_history 
                  where co_id=ech.co_id 
                  and ch_status='a') 
group by channel
       , TO_CHAR(ECH.CH_VALIDFROM,'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

I have below date and time values:

```
('16/10/2018 11:41:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AND TO_DATE
('16/10/2018 12:01:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')

('16/10/2018 12:38:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')  AND TO_DATE 
('16/10/2018 13:13:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 

('16/10/2018 20:21:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')   AND TO_DATE
('16/10/2018 20:30:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Comment: How did your determine your date and time value? from another table or parameter?

Comment: No its a manual entry

Comment: OK could you provide some sample data and expect result? it's a little hard to know your question for me

Comment: For the complete query given above the result is 89.
If I put the below value in place of ('17/10/2018 20:21:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AND TO_DATE ('17/10/2018 21:16:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')

Changing above with thsi value ('16/10/2018 11:41:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AND TO_DATE
('16/10/2018 12:01:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')

I get the result 243

Now I want to make a query where I can put both the inputs collectively and can get both outputs i.e. 89 and 243 together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've understood from your comments, you may want to define a range id for each range and include that in the `group by`, and put those ranges  in a CTE ( or a range table )

```
with inputs
AS
(
SELECT 1 in_range_id,
       TO_DATE('16/10/2018 11:41:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as start_dtime,
       TO_DATE('16/10/2018 12:01:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as end_dtime

FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,
       TO_DATE('16/10/2018 12:38:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
       TO_DATE('16/10/2018 13:13:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,
       TO_DATE('16/10/2018 20:21:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
       TO_DATE('16/10/2018 20:30:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
FROM dual
)
select in_range_id
       ,channel
       ,TO_CHAR(ECH.CH_VALIDFROM,'dd/mm/yyyy')
       , count(1) count 
from emcdu.ext_contract_history ech cross join inputs i
where ch_status='a' 
and ch_validfrom BETWEEN  i.start_dtime 
                     AND  i.end_dtime
and ch_validfrom=(select min(CH_VALIDFROM) 
                  from emcdu.ext_contract_history 
                  where co_id=ech.co_id 
                  and ch_status='a') 
group by in_range_id
         ,channel
         ,TO_CHAR(ECH.CH_VALIDFROM,'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

Comment: Hi Kaushik, Thanks for your answer but I am recieving the attached error while running the above command:

ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing

Comment: @Pawan : It seems you are using version older than 11g R2 , I have edited the answer. Please check now.

Comment: This query is sometimes working and sometimes it is taking too much long time to execute.

Comment: @Pawan : Nice to know that it's working. You may consider rewriting the logic to improve the performance of the query or add appropriate indexes/partitions on the date columns. But, I can't say much about that without knowing your data distribution and volume.

Answer (score 1):

How about little bit of *ORing* (i.e. put those conditions into the same `WHERE` clause, using the `OR` operator):

```
select   channel
       , to_char(ech.ch_validfrom, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
       , count(*) count 
from emcdu.ext_contract_history ech 
where ch_status = 'a' 
and (   ch_validfrom between to_date('17/10/2018 20:21:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
                         and to_date('17/10/2018 21:16:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
     or ch_validfrom between to_date('16/10/2018 11:41:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
                         and to_date('16/10/2018 12:01:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
     or ch_validfrom between to_date('16/10/2018 12:38:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')  
                         and to_date('16/10/2018 13:13:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
     or ch_validfrom between to_date('16/10/2018 20:21:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')   
                         and to_date('16/10/2018 20:30:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
    )
and ch_validfrom=(select min(ch_validfrom) 
                  from emcdu.ext_contract_history 
                  where co_id = ech.co_id 
                  and ch_status = 'a') 
group by channel
       , to_char(ech.ch_validfrom, 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am getting output as 
DSP 16/10/2018 817
DSP 17/10/2018 1963

Whereas I want the 4 Output i.e each output for each condition.

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't understand that you want to get 4 separate results. Well, it won't work that way, obviously. Did you try @Kaushik's suggestion? Looks like it should be OK.